# When making crockpot chili and adding raw hamburger, won't that make the chili greasy if not strained?

Tags: crockpot, chili

If you add raw ground beef, what about the grease in the meat mixing in with the chili? ill..

Comment: I edited your question to avoid off-topic health issues. We are happy to discuss flavor, but we're not qualified to address health claims.

Answer (score 2):

The amount of grease the meat exudes is dependent upon the amount of fat in the beef. If your beef is lean (<10% fat), you will not likely notice a difference in the greasiness in the final product by not straining. If your meat is fatty (ground beef in the US can contain up to 30% fat), then the final product will have noticeable grease. The fat contributes in a good way (IMO) to the flavor and mouth-feel of chili if the meat is in the 15% range.